# How to map one attribute to two properties in litElement?

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element, lit-html

I am working in a litElement project, and in a component, I have an attribute that needs to be mapped to a property, and computed with a function to another one, something like this:

```js
const calculateTwo(val) {
 return `${val} ${val}`
}

class MyElement extends LitElement {
  
  static get properties() {
    return {
      one: {
        type: String,
        attribute: 'foo',
      },
      two: {
        type: String,
        attribute: 'foo',
        reflect: false,
        converter: value => calculateTwo(value),
      },
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<my-component foo="bar"></my-component>
```

If I do this, `one` is not setted with 'bar', but `two` is correct

If I remove the property `two`, `one` works properly.

What would be the better approach to achieve this?

I can go with the `update` function, but I would like to know if there is a better approach.

I don't want to use a getter function to one of the properties, because the function of the converter is pretty heavy and I don't want it to be called everytime that I want to access the prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using property accessors could avoid calling to render twice.

```
const calculateTwo(val) {
 return `${val} ${val}`
}

class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      one: {
        type: String,
        attribute: 'foo',
      },
      two: {
        attribute: false
      }
    };
  }

  set one(value) {
    const oldValue = this._one;

    this.two = value;
    this._one = value;

    this.requestUpdate('one', oldValue);
  }

  get one() {
    return this._one;
  }

  set two(value) {
    const oldValue = this._two;

    this._two = calculateTwo(value);

    this.requestUpdate('two', oldValue);
  }

  get two() {
    return this._two;
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to apply a getter, then `updated` is your best bet

```js
const calculateTwo(val) {
 return `${val} ${val}`
}

class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      one: {
        type: String,
        attribute: 'foo',
      },
      two: {
        attribute: false
      }
    };
  }

  updated(changed) {
    if (changed.has('one')
      this.oneChanged()
  }

  oneChanged() {
    this.two = calculateTwo(this.one);
  }
}
```